# Insert query Database MySQL with registration form and servlet Java

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I have problem accessing database with servlet java. I want to add users with an html registration form.
this is the html:

```
<form name="registration-form" action="RegisterUser"  method="post">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label">Inserisci nome*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="inputName" placeholder="Nome">
        <span class="glyphicon  form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label">Inserisci cognome*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="inputLastname" placeholder="Cognome">
        <span class="glyphicon  form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label">Inserisci email*</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="glyphicon  form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label">Inserisci password (compresa tra 6 e 30 caratteri)*</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="inputFirstPassword" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon  form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label">Reinserisci password*</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputSecondPassword" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon  form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" >Registrati!</button>
</form>
```

This is the java class (InsertUser.java):

```
import java.sql.*;
public class InsertUser {
public static void main(String name, String surname, String email, String password) {
    PreparedStatement insert = null;
    String queryString = "INSERT INTO Utente(Nome, "
                        + "Cognome, Email, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        //Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/NoteDB";
        String connectionUser = "root";
        // String connectionPassword = "root";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, "");
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        insert = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);

        insert.setString(1, name);
        insert.setString(2, surname);
        insert.setString(3, email);
        insert.setString(4, password);

        insert.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

This is the servlet (RegisterUser.java)

```
  import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RegisterUser
 */
@WebServlet("/RegisterUser")
public class RegisterUser extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RegisterUser() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        //InsertUser myUser = new InsertUser();
        InsertUser.main(name, surname, email, password);

    }



    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

This is the error I get:
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg3pI.png)

I'm sorry that is a long question, but I am in despair :( Thanks everyone!

EDIT: in this picture you can see the mysql-connector.jar: [mysqlconnector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8XAb.png)

Comment: add mysql driver to the classpath

Comment: if you mean the mysqlconnector.jar i already added in my project. I added an image in the question

Comment: Have you put that jar to $CATALINA_HOME/lib too?

Comment: I GOT IT!! this line of code was the problem ----> "conn.setAutoCommit(false);"
Thanks everyone!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line conn.setAutoCommit(false);

Answer (score 0):

As Ramanlfc mentioned, you have to add mysql driver to your classpath.
You can do it natively via your ide, or use build managers, like maven, gradle or ant.
In maven, your pom.xml would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>your.app</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: if you mean the mysqlconnector.jar i already added in my project. I added an image in the question